# Method with different signature but derived from each other

Tags: c#, method-signature, derived-types

I have a very interesting question and didn't find any answer yet. Hope, someone can help me.

First I have a class hierarchy like

```
interface IA {}
class A : IA {}
class B : A {}
```

Next I have a class with several methods, all the same name but diffent signature with parameters of the derived classes

```
class Test
{
  public int Method(object dummy) { return 0; }
  public int Method(IA dummy) { return 1; }
  public int Method(A dummy) { return 2; }
  public int Method(B dummy) { return 3; }
}
```

The compiler doesn't complain, it recognizes all the different signatures

```
new Test().Method(new Object()) returns 0
new Test().Method(new A() as IA) returns 1
new Test().Method(new A()) returns 2
new Test().Method(new B()) returns 3
```

all as I would like to expect.

Now coming to my question. I have to determine during reflection which of the four methods fits best with it's signature to a given parameter type,i.e., if the parameter type is typeof(A) I have to find the 3rd method with the "A dummy" signature.

"IsInstanceOfType" or "IsAssignableFrom" doesn't work, since "A" is also instance of "object". I can check first if the types matches exact, but this solves the problem only if I do not accept interfaces.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this? The overload does exactly the same, calling the appropriate function at runtime. Please mention a use case so that we can understand the problem better.

Comment: Please clarify why the equality check doesn't solve the problem with interfaces.

Comment: Can you not use an enum in `IA` and set its value in the constructor of each class? Then you check the value of the enum and manually called the specific method.

Comment: I'm getting the parameter types and values during serialization and the call type may be a string, which must fall back to object in my excample. The use case is much more complex, since the parameters I get during serialization are not in the same order as in the called method, I have to sort them before.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`Type.GetMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy0h0z1(v=vs.110).aspx), it will find the most suitable method for your specified argument types.

```
typeof(Test).GetMethod("Method", new[] { typeof(Object) }) // Object
typeof(Test).GetMethod("Method", new[] { typeof(IA) }) // IA
typeof(Test).GetMethod("Method", new[] { typeof(A) }) // A
typeof(Test).GetMethod("Method", new[] { typeof(B) }) // B
typeof(Test).GetMethod("Method", new[] { typeof(CultureInfo) }) // Object
typeof(Test).GetMethod("Method", new[] { typeof(int) }) // Object
```

Assuming that you have the same `Test class and a new class`C`:

```
public class C : B
{
}
```

if you call

```
typeof(Test).GetMethod("Method", new[] { typeof(C) })
```

you will get `Test.Method (B dummy)` since there is no overload for type `C` and overload with `B` type is the most applicable one (the one which will be called if you pass object of type `C` to it).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but check for my comment above. Since the parameter types I get may not be in the same order as the expected method, I cannot use your suggestion.

But I think I will do a mix. When I find a suitable method in your way, then I invoke this method, otherwise I try to reorder my parameters in which case the type MUST match.